# Ruby Nested transaction: will nested transaction roll back if outside transaction is rolled back?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
model1.rb
def method1
   Model1.transaction do
      model2_ref_obj = Model2.find(some_id)
      model2_ref_obj.method1
  end
end


model2.rb
def method1
   Model2.transaction do
   ## so some work
   self.save!
   end
end
```

However, due to some issue, model1's transaction rollback, will inner transaction will also roll-back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby Nested transaction: will transaction inside will roll back if transaction outside is rolled back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52947659/ruby-nested-transaction-will-transaction-inside-will-roll-back-if-transaction-o)

Comment: @kiddorails yes both are same when I try to edit the Sub. I created a new link, instead of updating.

Answer (score 0):

If the error occurs in the second transactional block, the error is effectively rescued by that block, meaning the first transaction block thinks everything is hunky dory, goes ahead and commits the transactions - **including those that should be rolled back in the second transactional block**.

You have to be very careful when nesting transactions. The short answer is it varies depending on how the nesting is structured. Some good reading:

https://pragtob.wordpress.com/2017/12/12/surprises-with-nested-transactions-rollbacks-and-activerecord/