# In a nested transaction, will inner transaction roll back if outer transaction is rolled back?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**model1.rb**

```
def method1
   Model1.transaction do
      model2_ref_obj = Model2.find(some_id)
      model2_ref_obj.method1
  end
end
```

**model2.rb**

```
def method1
   Model2.transaction do
   ## so some work
   self.save!
   end
end
```

When `model1`'s transaction rolls back, will inner transaction also roll back?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: If `model2_ref_obj.method1` raises an exception. More specifically Rollback exception then Model1.transaction code will be rolled back, it's not the same for Model2.transaction as it is a separate transaction block altogether.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation on [ActiveRecord Nested Transactions](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Transactions::ClassMethods-label-Nested+transactions):

> transaction calls can be nested. By default, this makes all database statements in the nested transaction block become part of the parent transaction.

Meaning that if the parent transaction rollsback then the nested transaction will too, because they are part of the same transaction.